# I want to add mutiple API's and create a single API

Tags: api, unity-game-engine, sdk, facebook-unity-sdk

Hi guys m new to unity development and i want to add 3 SDKs to integrate in UNITY

1. FACEBOOK SDK
2. Countly
3. Adjust

and wanted to make a single SDK so that it can be used in future 
any idea how to do this?

Comment: "Hi guys m new to development" - perhaps try something less ambitious - 'hello world!" is the usual starting place

Comment: some times you have to run before u can walk

Comment: And sometimes you have to understand your limitations....

Comment: thankyour for your time sir

Comment: The closest thing I can think of to help you with your problem is the implementation of the "Encapsulation" principle. I'd start looking there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what functionality you want to use from those modules, but if they all pretty much do the same, you might define a common interface and have 3 adapters that make your modules fit to that interface.

```
interface ITrackingSdk
{
    void StartSession(string[] identifiers);
    ...
}

class FacebookTrackingSdk : ITrackingSdk
{
    private YourFacebookModule facebook;

    public static bool IsSupported { get { return true; } }

    public void StartSession(string[] identifiers)
    {
        facebook.InitializeBla(...);
    }
    ...
}

class CountlyTrackingSdk : ITrackingSdk { ... }
class AdjustTrackingSdk : ITrackingSdk { ... }
```

Then you have a factory that can create instances of your ITrackingSdk implementations, depending on the support on your current platform.

```
class TrackingSdkFactory
{
    public ICollection<ITrackingSdk> CreateSupportedTrackingSdks()
    {
        List<ITrackingSdk> sdks = new List...

        if (FacebookTrackingSdk.IsSupported)
            sdks.Add(new FacebookTrackingSdk());

        if (CountlyTrackingSdk.IsSupported)
            sdks.Add(new CountlyTrackingSdk());

        if (AdjustTrackingSdk.IsSupported)
            sdks.Add(new AdjustTrackingSdk());

        return sdks;
    }
}
```

And finally you might have some kind of Controller, that on start asks the Factory to provide all supported tracking Sdks, and then manages them.

And if people tell you to stick your goals lower, simply ignore them. Aim high and learn what you need to get there.

Comment: thankyou very much you provided me a goal, i have now the point where i have to go.. thanx alot